# Angular -- data-binding for a form that grows

Tags: forms, angularjs

I'm trying to create a form with data-binding that the user can add items to; they can click a button to add another text field (in this example it's the "plus" button). Here's a screenshot:

[image]

I've got things working now so more list items appear when the user clicks the button, but I can't find a clean and simple solution for how to let each form-element bind to a separate instruction in the model (theoretically in some sort of array in `$scope.form`).  So right now, every instruction text area always contains the same text (as expected, which is the problem).

Here's my view code (in jade, but should be readable):

```
 ol
    li( ng-repeat='instruction in form.instructions' )
       input( name='instruction[]' type='text' ng-model='form.instructions.text' )
    | <br>
    input( type='button' value='+' ng-click='addInstr()' )
```

Here's my controller code.

```
formControllers.controller('new-instruction-set-ctrl', function ($scope, $http) {
   $scope.form = $scope.form || {};
   $scope.form.instructions = [{}];

   $scope.addInstr = function() {
      $scope.form.instructions.push({});
   };
});
```

Comment: I was impressed with the ascii version:)

Comment: Heh, thanks :).  Wasted more time on it than I probably should've working the margins and stuff...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finally worked for me.  See live demo in [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/2dsi4kli04bzyWKIeKMo/preview).

View:

```
li( ng-repeat='instruction in form.instructions' )
   input( name='instruction[]' type='text' ng-model='form.instructions[$index].text')
```

I didn't have to change my controller at all.

`$index` is automatically provided by ng-repeat.